# Problem with execute two query functions in asp.net webform code behind

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a box to wait for and I want the box to be displayed first and removed after 5 seconds.
I wrote two jquery function for him
One for show and one for no show
The first function works correctly
But when I call the second function, the principles of the first function do not work and none of the functions are executed.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "OpenWaitingPagePopup()", true);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction2", "CloseWaitingPagePopup()", true);
    }
```

and my jquery functios is :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function OpenWaitingPagePopup() {
            $(".waiting-loader-layer").fadeIn("fast");
        }
        function CloseWaitingPagePopup() {
            $(".waiting-loader-layer").fadeOut();
        }
</script>
```

and my waiting popup is :

```
  <!-- waiting popup -->
  <div class="waiting-loader-layer">
   <div class="inner">
    <img src="https://www.pekbag.ir/images/ajax-loader-cs.gif" width="50" height="50">
    <span> Please wait ... </span>
</div>
 </div>
```

The jQuery file has also been added to the page correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functions on Page Load

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "OpenWaitingPagePopup()", true);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction2", "CloseWaitingPagePopup()", true);
```

they called with a delay of 5 seconds, but the delay is on server side, not on client side. The results of those is to render at the same time the two calls (show and hide) on browser - so its not working as you believe.

You must find an alternative way for your wait and must be on client side.

Answer (score 0):

This is my site :
https://www.pekbag.ir/Bag/%DA%A9%DB%8C%D9%81-%D9%84%D9%BE-%D8%AA%D8%A7%D9%BE
and I have used Ajax in some parts of the filter.
I think I have to implement the whole site filtering system with Ajax.
Thanks Aristos.